# Need query to ALTER more rows in one column without WHERE constrain

Tags: pymysql

I am looking for a query which I can use in `pymysql` to `UPDATE` the rows in one column without the `WHERE` constraint.

This is the query I used but it replaces all the `NULL` into `1`s:

```
UPDATE simplefocusstatistic_studentanswers
SET Player_id = null WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 1
```

Comment: You need an `UPDATE ... WHERE` statement. Why you can't use one? If you just alter the column to `INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` it will set all `NULL` values to `0`.

Comment: Your question does not make sense at all, sorry :-S What is your goal? Why you present an `UPDATE` statement, when you say you can't use one?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thank you for your replay. 
I am very new to this so I understand of my question is not well explained. I just can't figure out how to update this rows even if I put the values to 0. What I understood is that if I use:
`UPDATE simplefocusstatistic_studentanswers
SET Player_id = 1 WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 1`
All the rows that correspond to the `WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 1` will change into 1 and the problem is that I have more rows with `WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 1`. Insted of changing only 1 row it will change all of them.

Comment: If you change more rows than you want, you must narrow your `WHERE` clause according to which rows you want to change. Which rows do you want to change? Under which condition a `Player_id` should be changed? I think normally one would use `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` for this with auto-applied `ON DELETE SET NULL` or similiar.

Comment: @DanFromGermany in my simplefocusstatistic_id I have numbers from 1 till +200 and the numbers are being repeated, so the `WHERE` clause would change rows in the `Player_id` to 1 number, but that's not what I need. I need a query in which I can say: "let the player_id increment where the simplefocusstatistic_id is 2  " I was trying to use autoincrement but find my self in the problem where I can't have duplicated number because of the `UNIQUE KEY` which I need to be able to use autoincrement.

Comment: You can do that with `UPDATE simplefocusstatistic_studentanswers SET player_id=player_id+1 WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 2` but beware, auto increment primary keys in MySQL are not guaranteed to be sequencial. If this is a primary key from auto increment, you can have wholes, like 1,2,5,6,7... I am still not sure about your **real** requirement for this..

Comment: @DanFromGermany I also tried this but it would give the same problem. If I have `AUTOINCREMENT` and any `KEY` It wont allow me to have duplicate numbers in the same column which I need.

Comment: Lelo, it's in the nature of an ID to be unique. Why do you want to increment IDs (primary keys) at all? Imagine you have a bank account and the bank increments all the account numbers +1. Now the bank account from someone else is yours and someone else has got your account now. Would be bad na? We don't do things like that if this kind of rotation is not intended.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, my db is actually from a quiz app. The app didn't record the player id so I have to insert a "fake one" just for the sake of creating a python code for the future. So I am actually appointing Player_id to the questions played, so it is possible that player_id 1 played 8 questions (simplefocusstatistic_id) . I forgot to mention that player_id is a foreign key to another Studen_Player_id table which has a Primary key Playe_id including values vrom 1-11. So the actual amount of id's I will be using is 11 even though there are some questions which were played more then 11 times.